# Mongoose Is it possible to have two arrays unique?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I basically have a pivot table in mongoose, that contains two IDS from difference tables and they get populated. But the problem is I am struggling to allow make them unique, so you cannot have duplicate entry.

My schema:

```
var exampleSchema = new Schema (
    {
        exampID: [{ type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Test'}],
        testID: [{ type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'Example'}]
    }
```

So as you can see they are both arrays.

I have tried doing:

```
exampleSchema.index({exampID: 1, testID: 1}, {unique: true});
```

But i get thrown this error:

```
 MongoError: cannot index parallel arrays [exampID] [testID]
```

Surely by now Mongoose should have added support for this? Or is there already support for this? or a workaround?

Comment: This is a MongoDB error, not a Mongoose error. MongoDB doesn't support this, AFAIK.

Comment: @robertklep ah okay, do you know any ways around it?

Comment: Are you sure that you need _arrays_ of id's to `Test` and `Example`? If you don't, then I think it'll work.

Comment: @robertklep i built the database on including pivot tables and this pivot within this schema it populates both arrays you see, so yea i kind of do as i do have other tables where i have multi index but only has one array

Comment: AFAIK, you can't create unique compound indexes across arrays with MongoDB. I don't know a workaround :(

Comment: @robertklep darn, so used to using laravel schemas to handle issues like that ... thanks anyway!